# My Seaborn heatmap is showing multiple scales

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap

My seaborn heatmap is showing multiple scales (for each column I presume)
Attached an image showing the code, data & chart.
Wondering how I can remove the multiple scales on the right and show only 1.

```py
clustered_heatmap = clustered_points.groupby("Predicted Clusters").sum()
clustered_heatmap = clustered_heatmap.drop(clustered_heatmap.columns[0], axis = 1)
clustered_heatmap
```

[image: Code & chart]

Comment: Please do not post code/data/error messages as images. Post the text directly here on SO. You should also provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Just restart your notebook. The same heatmap has been recreated several times, adding a new colorbar on each turn.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
# Create heatmap
 
plt.figure(figsize=(16,9))
 
sns.heatmap(clustered_heatmap)
```